# What is the equivalent of set innerHTML with lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

What is the equivalent of JavaScript innerHTML set in lxml?

E.g.

```
myElem.innerHTML = "<a href='...'><img src='...'></a>"
```

Comment: The future generations will benefit from my great wisdom: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: And now while you are here, please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python code:

```py
from lxml.html import HtmlElement, fragment_fromstring

def set_inner_html(elem: HtmlElement, html: str):
    """Replace innerHTML of a lxml element."""

    # Clear the element contents
    child: HtmlElement
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        elem.remove(child)

    # Create and add new contents
    content = fragment_fromstring(html)
    elem.append(content)
```